# How can I declare and subscribe many Queues to an TopicExchange without static config?

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a Spring-Boot app containing many @Service components for handling event-typed AMQP messages. These messages are published by another component to a single ExchangeTopic separated by routing-keys.

How should I create and subscribe the Queues to the TopicExchange once the application starts and avoid maintaining a massive configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply invoke `RabbitAdmin.declareQueue()` and `declareBinding()`  as needed.

For each new queue, you can either create a new `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` or add the queue to an existing container.

Adding queues to a container cancels the existing consumers and immediately creates new ones so there is a (short) interruption.

Comment: Would it matter performance wise to create multiple containers (~70)? If creating one container, how would you bind the added queues to the different messagehandlers?

Comment: Probably not a big deal for that number but YMMV. The real gating factor is total message volume. If you need a different handler for each then a container per queue makes most sense. Otherwise you'll need a delegating handler which routes on the received queue.